# Node.js+express proxy ssl

Tags: node.js, ssl, proxy, express

I'm trying to write a reverse proxy in node.js using express, and it works fine for http requests. The problem is that when requesting https it never responds, and the browser states that the proxy refused to connect. 
Here is the working code for http requests:

```
var   app = express(),
      http=require('http');

app.configure(function(){ /* express stuff to log and use routes and the like */ });

http.createServer(app).listen(8000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + 8000);
});

app.all('*', proxy);
var request=require('request');

var proxy=function(req,resp){
    var data={
        url:req.url,
        headers: {
            'Connection': 'keep-alive'
        }
    }
    var proxy=request(req.url);
    proxy.pipe(resp);
}
```

Now, as for SSL, i am currently trying with:

```
var https=require('https'),
    fs=require('fs');

https.createServer({
        key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/ssl/server.key', 'utf8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/ssl/server.crt', 'utf8')
      },app).listen(8001, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + 8001);
});
```

The proxy can be used from anywhere requiring `50.56.195.215:8000` for HTTP and `50.56.195.215:8001` for SSL. It has no security whasoever, so don't log in to anything important =D

I'm using a self signed SSL Certificate, and i guess it's kind of silly of me to try to do such a thing, but i don't have any ideas left :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is use the great existing library [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) from Nodejitsu. If you want to write your own, at least study their source code academically.

Some notes on your approach above:

- You aren't handling HTTP methods other than GET (POST, PUT, DELETE, etc). These exist. You must handle them if you want your proxy to actually work. Every time you call `request(req.url)`, `request` is making a GET request by default.

Comment: While I agree node-http-proxy is the way to go, he is actually globbing the methods with app.all()

Comment: he means to use other than get when sending the request from the proxy, not catching them by express. I had not noticed that as i had not tried with any post yet.
As for node-http-proxy ... i was considering using it, but i could not find a way to make it work as a transparent proxy :(

Comment: So you can't take an existing project known to work and get it installed and running, but you are hoping to write one on your own, or get stackoverflow to help you write another one? It might be time to take a step back and re-evaluate your position on this one, but good luck nonetheless!

Comment: the thing is that node-http-proxy doesn't seem to have the ability to do so (https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/209) ... it proxies requests from one known server to another, and i want a transparent proxy that proxies everything to a server (i mean ... call google.com, is sent to server, server requestos google.com and returns response)

Comment: Have you looked at an actual http proxy (not reverse proxy) project like squid? http://www.squid-cache.org/

Comment: yep ... i still want to do something on my own ... just experimenting, you know ;)
I'll wait for some days to see if anyone has an idea on how this could be achieved, and if nothing happens, i'll just move on to something else marking yours as the best posible answer XD

Answer (score 1):

For HTTPS, you need to be able to handle HTTP Connects and also impersonate the destination server. You will need to have a Certificate for this.

You can try using this.
https://github.com/noeltimothy/noelsproxy

Copy the directory "magical" that contains a certificate as well as a key and then use noelsproxy. Remember to add the ca.pem to your trusted root store on your system.

If you are using windows, do this:
certutil -addstore -enterprise -f \"Root\" ./magical/ca.pem

Let me know if you have any issues. I'm willing to fix them immediately.